# Comparing filenames using the same case conversion rules as a given filesystem

Tags: winapi

I need to compare filenames in order to check if they are equivalent or not on a given file system.

For example on a standard Windows NTFS volume following filenames are equivalent:

```
TEST.TXT <--> Test.txt
```

but following filenames are not:

```
HÉLLO.TXT <--> Héllo.txt
```

Is there a Win32 function that allows to check the equivalence of two filenames ?

Comment: You'll have to explain why accented characters are a problem, Windows has been a Unicode operating system for over 20 years.

Comment: http://www.siao2.com/2005/10/17/481600.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant: I edited the question, it was actually pointless.

Answer (score 0):

many functions exist - all what need - case insensitive unicode string compare
lstrcmpiW, _wcsicmp, RtlEqualUnicodeString, ...

Comment: What about the issue of locale?